# ConfigurationProperties with prefix is not working

Tags: maven, spring-boot, java-10, configurationproperties

I am very new in spring boot and creating my first application. While creating data source I am using @ConfigurationProperties with prefix and properties to be read from application.property.

However, this setup doesn't seems to work for me and my program is not running.

My properties from application.property file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/appboot
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
```

My Code:

```
@Configuration
public class PersistentConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
    @Primary
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
}
```

I understand that `@ConfigurationProperties` is not reading the properties from my file. If I provide details in builder method as below, it works well:

```
return DataSourceBuilder.create()
.url("jdbc:h2:file:~/appboot")
.username("sa")
.password("")
.driverClassName("org.h2.Driver")
.build();
```

My pom.xml file has:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

My Repository class:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.boot.model.Shipwreck;

public interface ShipwreckRepository extends JpaRepository<Shipwreck, Long>{

}
```

My Main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName.
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at com.boot.App.main(App.java:15) [classes/:na]
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName.
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.validate(HikariConfig.java:1059) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:109) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
>       at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:51) ~[flyway-core-5.0.7.jar:na]
>       at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.DatabaseFactory.createDatabase(DatabaseFactory.java:67) ~[flyway-core-5.0.7.jar:na]
>       at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1634) ~[flyway-core-5.0.7.jar:na]
>       at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:1168) ~[flyway-core-5.0.7.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:66) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>       ... 18 common frames omitted

Please let me know if I need to provide any other information as well.

Comment: How are you accessing the database? `Repository` , `DataSource `,  `JdbcTemplate `? If, for example, you use [Spring Data JPA Repositories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-data-jpa-repositories) you don't need anything except the properties.

Comment: I think I am using it through JPA repository only. `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` is added in my pom.xml and I edited my question with my repository class. It is empty as of now.

Comment: Can you add the corresponding code to avoid any assumptions?

Answer (score 1):

Check if this  helps:

```
import java.util.Map;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
public class PersistentConfiguration {

  Map<String, String> datasource;

  public DataSource getDatasources() {
    System.out.println("datasources ==="+datasource);
    return DataSourceBuilder.create()
        .url(datasource.get("url"))
        .username(datasource.get("username"))
        .password(datasource.get("password"))
        .driverClassName(datasource.get("driver-class-name"))
        .build();
  }

  public void setDatasource(Map<String, String> datasource) {
    this.datasource = datasource;
  }
}
```

application.properties file:

```
datasource[url]=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3000/andatabase?useSSL=false
datasource[username]=root
datasource[password]=password
datasource[driver-class-name]=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

In Controller:

```
@Autowired
PersistentConfiguration config;

@GetMapping("/language")
public ResponseEntity control() {

config.getDatasources();

return new ResponseEntity("success", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot give us many facilities to create applications, for example if you want to use the database H2, you only need to add the dependency to your `pom` file and add the respective properties in the `application.properties` file, there are some default properties that allow transparent communication between the database and the application, as for example:

```
# To save the db in memory
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test

# To save the db in a file within the project
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:./db/test
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.platform=h2
```

I mean `DataSource` configuration is controlled by external configuration properties in `spring.datasource.*`, so you don't need define `PersistentConfiguration` class, it is enough to correctly define those properties for the application works well. Make sure you have added dependency `H2` in your `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Also you can check the data in the db:

```
http://<host>:<port>/<context-path>/h2-console/
```

For example:

```
http://localhost:8080/my-first-app/h2-console
```